# clearInterval() throwing 'No overload matches this call' when used in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to write a setInterval function (which works as expected), but it should be cleared once this.attempts hits the level of this.retryTimes. When I try to call clearInterval() as shown below, I am given the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(intervalId: Timer): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Timer'.
      Type '() => void' is missing the following properties from type 'Timer': ref, unref
  Overload 2 of 2, '(handle?: number): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

```
const retryLoop = () => {
      if (this.shouldRetry) {
        this.attemptRetry();
        this.showError = true;
      }
      this.attempts = this.attempts + 1;
    };
    const stopRetry = () => {
      clearInterval(retryLoop);
    }
      setInterval(retryLoop, 5000);
      if (this.attempts > this.retryTimes) {
        clearInterval(stopRetry)
      }
    }
```

Comment: `retryLoop` is the function, its not going to work with `clearInterval(retryLoop);` and `stopRetry` is a function its not going to work with `clearInterval(stopRetry)`, ... rtm

Comment: `setInterval` function returns a value when it is called. Assign the value to a `variable` and call cleartInterval with that `variable`. e.g. `var myTimer = setInterval(...);` and then `clearInterval(myTimer);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to clear an interval (with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)) you need to take the return from [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) you almost have it:

```
function something() {
    const retryLoop = () => {
        if (this.shouldRetry) {
            this.attemptRetry();
            this.showError = true;
        }
        this.attempts = this.attempts + 1;
    };
    const stopRetry = setInterval(retryLoop, 5000);
    if (this.attempts > this.retryTimes) {
        clearInterval(stopRetry);
    }
}
```

You can ignore the `function something() {` line.. there was just a mismatched close bracket at the end so I wrapped it (to run an auto formatter on it)

Answer (score 0):

**clearInterval(xxxxx)  :**  here xxxx should be the **setInterval** itself , not the function (**retryLoop**) .

---

w3school link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

The clearInterval() method clears a timer set with the setInterval() method.

`myVar = setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);`

`clearInterval(myVar);`

---

changed the timer from '5000' to '1000' just for quick execution .

```js
let attempts = 1;
const retryTimes = 10;

const retryLoop = () => {
    console.log("retry no : "+attempts)
    attempts = attempts + 1;
    if (attempts > retryTimes) {
        console.log("---- ending retry ----")
        clearInterval(attemptRetry);
    }
};

var attemptRetry = setInterval(retryLoop, 1000);
```